# Underline UITextField does not work in StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm having multiple textfields for sign-up page and I have used stack view in it. When I try to assign underline colour to my `UITextField` it does not work. But if I do the same w/o StackView then it works fine.

```
extension UITextField {
    func underlined() {

        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = themeColor.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

nameTextField.underlined()
ageTextField.underlined()
```

[image: StackView Settings]

Comment: Are you sure the text field's frame isn't be changed after the call to `underlined`? The layer's frame will not be updated automatically.

Comment: Yes. As this works if I keep them out of StackView

Comment: No, you are not sure. The stack view could be causing the frames of the text fields to change after you call `underlined`. Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: How StackView could make problem ? Can you please guide how to debug this as it is on Storyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy added my StackView settings to question.

Comment: Anyone please help me out with this...

Comment: Hey @Nitesh, did you find the answer?